# Recursive regex in data types and arguments

Tags: regex, recursion, attributes

I'm attempting to get some words from the following word's group with Regex.

```
InArgument(njl:JObject)
InArgument(x:String)
OutArgument(scg:List(x:String))
OutArgument(scg:List(x:String))
InArgument(scg:Dictionary(x:String, sd:DataTable))
InArgument(scg:ICollection(x:Boolean))
InArgument(scg:IEnumerable(x:Object))
```

Regex:

```
(In|Out|InOut)Argument\(.*:(.*)\)
```

It works fine for the first and second line, but not with List, Dictionary, ICollection and IEnumerable.

I need group separation because the captured data will be used to make documentation.

Thank you!

EDIT:

The first datatypes do not all end with ) You could try `(In|Out|InOut)Argument\([^:]+:([^()\s]+)[()]` regex101.com/r/lLj28g/1 – The fourth bird (yesterday)

It solves my question partially, because I need to get arguments and sub arguments too... thank you "The fourth bird"!

Comment: You should definitely tag the regex engine you use for the correct use of recursion (or even if it's *possible*), since not all regex flavours support it.

Comment: Is "JObject, String, List, List, Dictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable" the expected output?

Comment: Try replacing the first `.*` with `[^:]*`

Comment: The first datatypes do not all end with `)` You could try `(In|Out|InOut)Argument\([^:]+:([^()\s]+)[()]`https://regex101.com/r/lLj28g/1

Comment: Thank you for answering! It solves my question partially, because I need to get arguments and sub arguments too... thank you "The fourth bird"!

Comment: xcan, my expected result is the following table: 
Direction|Type
In|JObject
In|String
Out|List(String)
Out|List(String)
In|Dictionary(String, DataTable)
In|ICollection(Boolean)
In|IEnumerable(Object)